# About error in multitasking cross application

Tags: c#, multithreading, rest, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms cross application that use a rest client to invoke a remote service.

So I use async method but when in try to build or run it an error is displayed:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State

> Error Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
>
> Nome file: 'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll'
>   in Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
>   in Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection
>   1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
>      in Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection
>   1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
>   in Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() TEST1.Droid

I try to add a using System.Threading.Tasks in portable project but still get the error.

How can I use async/await in portable cross application ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745637/could-not-load-assembly-microsoft-threading-tasks-dll

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389315/microsoft-threading-tasks-extensions-in-xamarin-mono-projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following approach

```
1) Open your Package Manager Console, and run the following commands
2) Uninstall-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async -Force 
3) Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async -Version 1.0.166-beta -Pre
```

Clean your solution and then rebuild;

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply. 

During the  uninstall i have a error: 

PM> Uninstall-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async -Force 
Uninstall-Package : Package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async' to be uninstalled could not be found in project 'TEST1.Droid'
At line:1 char:1
+ Uninstall-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Uninstall-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UninstallPackage 
   Command

I am using VS2015 U3.

Comment: You don't have it installed, thats why you get that error. Begin at step 3) instead

Comment: Ok, thanks Zroq , i have some problem with Microsoft.Bcl.Async!